# DocSpring - is there a way to find a PDF and retrieve info from the PDF?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to find PDFs in DocSpring based on the text in the PDF, and if so, is there a way to get the info that was added to the PDF from a form?

For example, if users filled out and submitted a form, and this process did two things: 1) saved their info it a database, and 2) created a PDF on DocSpring for each user, is there a way to get the PDF for a specific user? And is there a way to get the other info that the user submitted through the form?

The "Submissions" tab on DocSpring doesn't seem to have any search capability. And I'm trying to figure out a way to do this with a GET request. I have the user names, and I need to get other info from the form that was filled out because some of the info was not saved to the database when the form was submitted.

Comment: Hi @FrancoOrtega, sorry I just saw your question! Sorry about the lack of search support on our submissions page, that's a great to idea to add some indexing so that you can search for keywords in the submission data. We will definitely add this to our roadmap!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. It requires having the submission ID of the document (PDF in this case) and sending it to DocSpring with their getSubmission method. Their docs have a great example of how to connect to DocSpring and use this method to get a bunch of info about the document.

https://docspring.com/docs/api/get_submission.html

Although, to get the actual data that was added to the document (such as user info, in this instance), you have to change `{ includeData: false }` to `{ includeData: true }`.